# Spring security does not work

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting an error when I try to login (or, when I abort the HTTP Basic dialog with escape)

> HTTP Status 401 - PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select
>   username,authority from authorities where username = ?]; nested
>   exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
>   "authorities" does not exist Position: 32

However, shouldn't it  be enough with the two query attributes below when I want to use group based security? Do I need to define query for this attribute to? `authorities-by-username-query=""` Why isn't it working?

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                    users-by-username-query="..."
                                    group-authorities-by-username-query="..." />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Source from JdbcDaoImpl:

```
if (enableAuthorities) {
    dbAuthsSet.addAll(loadUserAuthorities(user.getUsername()));
}

if (enableGroups) {
    dbAuthsSet.addAll(loadGroupAuthorities(user.getUsername()));
}
```

Comment: Bad SQL grammar has nothing to do with Spring Security. Check what your tables and columns are called.

Comment: _"...relation "authorities" does not exist "_ should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Uhh, why would I need it when I AM USING GROUP BASED AUTHENTICATION? After reading the documentation it seems like you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can't find a sentence in my question where I state that either, I was wondering why I need it.

Comment: @LuckyLuke I don't know Spring security, but it seems to me like it's trying to connect to a database expecting a table which you don't have. What is the required Spring security config?

Comment: Did you create the required [database schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-schema.html)

Comment: @GriffeyDog I have a schema like that yes, but with own names etc. However I got the data as required. But I don't understand why I need to provide the sql for authorities by username when I am using group based security as already said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that enableGroups is still set to false? It doesn't seem like there's a way to configure that using the jdbc-user-service element in the namespace configuration. The Spring JIRA issue [SEC-1625](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1625) seems to confirm this.

Try declaring the JdbcDaoImpl instance as a bean instead.